# How to make Mobile Safari open email links in the Gmail app?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, gmail, mobile-safari

Is it possible to make a mobile Safari open email links directly to the native Gmail app, rather than open up to Apple's Mail.app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way (yet) to change that without jailbreak tweak. Apple forces you to use Safari and (in this case also) Mail.app.

You can find the tweak here: http://www.webpronews.com/jailbreak-tweak-lets-you-make-chrome-your-default-ios-browser-2012-06

Comment: You mean, Apple forces you to use their mail app.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to change the default mail app on iOS for mailto: links clicked in a web browser. Developers of Gmail app could develop a Safari extension that injects a JavaScript file in every webpage. Such file could modify the DOM, replacing all mailto: links into gmail: links. It would be only few lines of code. They could develop such extensions for other popular web browsers.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/injecting_a_script_into_a_webpage

Comment: You cannot inject javascript without running the user manually running your extension.

Comment: But this is expected. This extension would be provided as an option from the third party mail app :p

Comment: Yes, that would be feasible but would still require the user to run that for the page before clicking the link.